# Using JS to find screen height, then apply it to a div class through CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, liquid

I'm working on a single-page scroll-to webdesign, and can't get this code to work.

What I'm trying to do is get the screen height of the user through JavaScript.

Then I want to apply this screen height to my div class, so that I'll always have a container that is the size of the users screen resolution. A liquid design that always fits the screen, so to speak.

Here's a short example of where I want the variable screen height to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function matchHeight() {
$('.container').css('height',$(window).height);
};
</script>
```

`<div class="container"> I want this container to be the height of the users screen resolution. </div>`

```
.container { width:100%; height: /* javascript value */ }
```

Help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've added a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonvdh/LR7dq/) of my complete document.

Comment: be a man and use CSS only

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski be a man and provide him with a CSS solution :)

Comment: is there a reason to think there could be another screen height than 100%?

Comment: I tried 100% height. And provided my html, body and .container with it. Didn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What  you are asking for is not difficult at all. All it requires is one nice JavaScript function and a few quick minor changes to your HTML code.

First, give your "container" `<div>` an id by making some quick changes to your HTML;

```
<div class="container" id="container">
I want this container to be the height of the users screen resolution. 
</div>
```

Next define a JavaScript variable that refers to it:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
```

Then use this neat function that I use all the time to get the dimensions of the screen using JavaScript:

```
function resize() {
    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
    viewportheight = window.innerHeight
}

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
    viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
}

// older versions of IE

else {
    viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
}
container.style.height = viewportheight+"px";
}
```

Notice that I put `container.style.height = viewportheight+"px";` in the function. This means that every time `resize();` is called we will update the dimensions of the browser and reapply those dimensions to the container `<div>`.

We will call the `resize();` function in the body every time the page resizes, as well as when the page first loads, using this HTML:

```
<body onload="resize()" onresize="resize()">
```

The function will resize the container `<div>` to the full page height. Let me know if you have problems with this, or have any questions!

Comment: First off, thank you very much for the help!

I applied the ID to my div, then added the javascript to the head. Lastly, I added the body onload, and a background color to my .container css 

If the code works, and the div is changed to the height I just received from the javascript, the background color should span my whole screen. Which it doesn't. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try putting an alert after `container.style.height = viewportheight+"px";` Something like `alert(viewportheight);` so we can see if the correct value of the variable is being passed. Also, it would be super helpful if you could provide a link to the actual page where this is happening, so I can see it for myself. Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, you're new, I forgot! People on StackOverflow will destroy you for using pastebin. There's this great little tool called jsfiddle that let's you instantly get results from your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code. You should use that instead: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Right, my bad! I'll get one of those right away. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Strange...all I did was remove the `<body onload="resize()" onresize="resize()">` and replace it with `window.onload=resize();` and `window.onresize=resize();` in JavaScript, and now it seems to be working. See the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/LR7dq/5/ Try this on your page, and see if it works as well?

Comment: It does seem to be working in Fiddle, but copying the code exactly into my document doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Can you post a link to your actual page?

Comment: By the way, you can view the source of the fiddle I posted by adding `/show` to the end of the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/LR7dq/5/show/

Comment: Can you give me a link to the index.html, or is it on your localhost?

Comment: Here's a download link to all my files, since it's local host. http://we.tl/Xy0QHXRBdC

Comment: Fixed it! There were a few tiny things wrong with the code that made it non-functional. Download link: http://www.mediafire.com/?wq2kvg7i7pr2a0b Give that a shot :)

Comment: You sir, are an absolute hero. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: You can repay me by upvoting my answer and marking it at the best one :)

Answer (score 1):

You Can not use JS code in css.

You may do what you want like this:

```
$('.container').height($(window).height());
```

or

```
$('.container').height($(document).height());
```

whether you want window or document height.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Tried applying these snippets, didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN NOT do following stuff

```
.container { width:100%; height: /* javascript value */ }
```

However you can set height to some value and later alter it using `jQuery`'s `.css()` API.

Also make sure that you call your `matchHeight()` function from within `$(documeent).ready()`.

```
===========================
```

You can change your `container` class to

```
.container { position:absolute: width:100%; height: 100%; }

===========================
```

OR you can use `css media queries`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the comment!

I'm trying to avoid using position:absolute. Tired of having to measure everything up before I can place a div.