# How to calculate the height of a HTML DIV Element in relation to existing display resolution with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a html div element and now i want to calculate the height in relation to existing  display resolution. How can i set the height the css code dynamically? Something like this, but more flexible:

```
 <div style="height:700px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;">
```

The div muste be have this css styling as default:

```
 position: fixed; top: 35px;
```

Comment: well, CSS is for setting styles not to calculate it. Use javascript for that.

Comment: Find out what top `35px` is in `%` and then work out the height (100 - `top` = `height`).

Comment: ok but how can i calculate this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc -- `calc(100% - 35px)`

Comment: Have a look at my answer (new jsfiddle) and see if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the div to extend the bottom of the page, give it `bottom:0;`.
If you also want it to stretch to left and right, since it's `position:fixed;` you can give it `left:0;` and `right:0;` too.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/9TEZL/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but I think it can be like this:

```css
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 70px);
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    top: 35px;
    left :35px;
}
```

Comment: Ok but the calc function is not support by any browser !

Comment: @Marwief then remove the height and set `bottom: 0` like BeatAlex answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry also I couldn not understand the question but if you want to get screen resolution, you must do it with js,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);
 </script>
```

then dynamically set style with computed height something like that,

```
 getElementById('DIV_ID').style.height=COMPUTED_HEIGHT;
```

Comment: And I think this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444510/using-js-to-find-screen-height-then-apply-it-to-a-div-class-through-css